# How can I get the value from combobox in window form application form

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

```
string connectionstring6 
    ="server=xxx;database=PM2;UID=tccxplxan;password=plantcc"; 
SqlConnection con6 = new SqlConnection(connectionstring6); 
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TranCode FROM intern_code1 where 
  status = '1'", con6); 
con6.Open(); 
SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader(); 
while (sqlReader.Read()) 
{comboBox2.Items.Add(sqlReader["TranCode"].ToString()); }
sqlReader.Close(); 
con6.Close();
```

Now I'm develop the window form application with C# there have 2 user type 
one is for planner User(UserA) 
the second user is Transportation User(UserB). 
      First The planer need to create the Document which is related to Transportation user if the planer create the doc and the the Transportation fill the detail the job will be done. What I'm trying to do is to make dropdown (combobox) list which serve for UserB show the Doc ID(Drop Down) that UserB didn't finish their job by status on the table . Now I am on the part that can show the exact display on combobox but there have no value on that

Comment: What is the code doing? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Share the code which tries to get the selected value from the combobox.

Comment: Now I'm develop the window form application with C#  there have 2 user type one is for planner User(UserA) the second user is  Transportation User(UserB). First The planer need to create the Document which is related to Transportation user  if the planer create the doc and the the Transportation fill the detail the job will be done. What I'm trying to do is to make dropdown (combobox)  list which serve for UserB show the Doc ID(Drop Down) that UserB didn't finish their job by status on the table . Now I am on the part that can show the exact display on combobox but there have no value on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understood your question, but if you want to get the selected value, then call the event method on select:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            String newSelectedProcress = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```

If the comboBox is empty, you have to check the sqlReader.

Comment: Don't forget to add `this.comboBox1.SelectedValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged);` into your Designer.cs of the class that created the comboBox.

Comment: Thanks. 
The value that show is System.Data.DataRowView  The exact value is A00000001.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `sqldatareader` to retrieve value you should specify the type and index column.

```
while (sqlReader.Read())
{  
    comboBox2.Items.Add(sqlReader.GetName(0));
}
sqlReader.Close();
con6.Close();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Comment: Could you explain more I didn't got that. Now I'm got the display value then how can I got the value after i select the display on combo box . Thanks

Comment: iam sorry, maybe interpret the question differently,. to get data/display from combobox. you could use `combobox2.text`